# Android packaging failed when gradle build with error no 3

Tags: android, gradle, apk, unreal-engine4, packaging

I tried android package using jekins with firebase plugin in UE4.26. But I failed android packaging with error no 3, I tried find error no 3, I can't find info about error no 3 and I have no solution. Help me please.

```
23:25:36   File ../../../Client/MyProject/Plugins/EasyFirebasePro/Source/EasyFirebase/../ThirdParty/firebase_cpp_sdk/Android/firebase_dependencies.gradle copied to C:/Jenkins/workspace/Client/MyProject/Intermediate/Android/arm64/gradle/app/firebase_dependencies.gradle
 23:25:36   Fixing minSdkVersion; NDK level above 19 requires minSdkVersion of 21 (arch=arm64)
 23:25:36   Deleting unneeded file C:\Jenkins\workspace\Client\MyProject\Intermediate\Android\arm64\gradle\permission_library\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml.
 23:25:36   
 23:25:36   Creating rungradle.bat to work around commandline length limit (using unused drive letter Z:)
 23:25:36   Making .apk with Gradle...
 23:25:37   
 23:25:37   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
 23:25:37   
 23:25:37   * What went wrong:
 23:25:37   Could not set process working directory to 'Z:\': could not set current directory (errno 3)
 23:25:37   
 23:25:37   * Try:
 23:25:37   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
 23:25:37   
 23:25:37   * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
 23:25:37   Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
 23:25:37   ERROR: cmd.exe failed with args /c "C:\Jenkins\workspace\Client\MyProject\Intermediate\Android\arm64\gradle\rungradle.bat" :app:assembleDebug
 23:25:37 Took 6.7540497s to run UnrealBuildTool.exe, ExitCode=6
 23:25:37 UnrealBuildTool failed. See log for more details. (C:\Jenkins\workspace\UnrealEngine\Engine\Programs\AutomationTool\Saved\Logs\UBT-.txt)
 23:25:37 AutomationTool exiting with ExitCode=6 (6)
 23:25:37 BUILD FAILED
```

Comment: The main error is `Could not set process working directory to 'Z:\': could not set current directory (errno 3)` - so the question is what is wrong with your drive `Z:\` any why want's gradle to use it?

Comment: I'm have not enough knowledge about gradle. Z drive is default path when I packaing andorid build. that is not my meaning. but usually Z drive work well @Robert

Answer (score 0):

You need to head to your build.gradle file (app) and change your minSdkVersion to 21.

Happy Coding! :)